# Page freezes on Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, performance, mobile

I'm testing on a webpage which displays a list of products, with photos, names, prices, etc. It works fine when I views it on my PC. When I visits the same page on mobile phones (Android and iPhone), the page first loads all its contents, and then freezes for few seconds, and then works again. When it freezes, I tried to scroll the screen up and down and it does nothing, and then after few seconds, it responds with all these actions. Any guess on what causes the freeze? There is some JS runs when the page loads, but it works just fine on browsers on PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your code. If you are displaying high resolution images on the device, it will slow down the scrolling. Also if you are downloading any data on the main UI thread, it will also cause the freeze which you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes on mobile if you're loading a lot of items or data at the same time it can take mobile phones a second to render all the new information. Perhaps loading less information could be a solution?

Comment: But in my case, all the content of the page has been loaded before the freeze. I tried to debug using Safari Web Inspector and actually there's no JS events running when it freeze.